# How to create multiply client id for android application: debug and release version

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, google-play-services

In [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0) in `credentials` tab for generate client id, I pass SHA1 based on key *.jks (for release version). The release version works fine, but when I start debug version of application isn`t work. I can pass only one SHA1, and when I pass SHA1 based on debug.keystore, my release version doesn't work. How to do something for working with both?

This I do for Google plus API.

Comment: Have u got solution?

Comment: Yes, its really easy. You can add client OAuth 2.0 credentials as much as you need in you google api console.